# How to make a aspx website compatitble with mobile

Tags: asp.net, mobile, cross-browser

I have created a Login webpage in asp.net with oracle as back end. Its kind of portal thing.

When I am loading the web page in laptop browser its completely fine.
When I am loading the web page in mobile browser its loading as normal with no problems.

But I want to load the page with a customized view when browsed in iPhone/mobile . Can anyone give me idea how to do it please?

Example: when facebbook.com loads in iphone it uses the same databse but completely different view than in desktop.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046588/how-does-the-development-of-a-mobile-website-differ-from-a-normal-one/7047356#7047356

Answer (score 1):

The best way I find to do this is to add a separate mobile site (e.g. m.domain.com), and have mobile browsers redirect to this.

For adding a seperate mobile site, [this guide](http://buildinternet.com/2011/01/add-a-mobile-landing-page-to-your-site/) seems to explain it very well.

Comment: Thank you very much Nick. I really got the concept. But what I am now concerned about is that: I have created a asp.net web application but will I need to recode it again for the sub domain and if so, how to do it. Or is there an easy way.